# Compute the galois group of the splitting field of $x^5+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory

[image]

The roots of this polynomial are $(-1)\zeta^n$. Where $\zeta$ is the 5th root of unity.  So the splitting field should just be $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.  This has galois group $\mathbb{Z}/4$ since it's just a cyclotomic extension.  Is this correct?

Source: https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/363/docs/F17_510ab.pdf

Comment: It seems fine to me

Comment: This has been discussed already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319939/galois-group-of-x51).